# How to show clicked image in viewpager From Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I'm Developing Wallpapers App with Backend as Firebase. The List of Wallpapers From Firebase Database are shown in Recycler Gridview until here all the things done are working good. From here What I want is When User clicked on the image the clicked image is shown on ViewPager in another activity(Details.java).

**Here are the sample images of what i want** [1](https://hmp.me/cqk9)   [2](https://hmp.me/cqla)   [3](https://hmp.me/cqlb)   [4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17vTv9MkBojLhkdo8u4QG1A01Oqk4XyoK)

From Past two days, I'm trying to get this by using different solutions from various sources on the Internet but I didn't get the solution.

If anyone knows the solution, Please Share with me.  Thanks in Advance

Some of my code is here and if more needed I'll Provide.

ImageListActivity.java

```
    package in.developerwithlove.nithiinhdwallpapers;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ImagesListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements UploadImgAdapter.OnItemClickListener, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    String Admobadunit;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private UploadImgAdapter mAdapter;
    private ProgressBar mProgressCircle;
    private List<ImgUpload> mUploads;
    private List<ImgUpload> mUploads2;
    private List<ImgUpload> mUploads3;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private List<ImgUpload> mHomeRecentPostList;
    private AdView mAdView;
    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mDataBaseRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_images_list );
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
        setSupportActionBar( toolbar );
        mRecyclerView = findViewById( R.id.recycler_view1 );
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize( true );
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager( new GridLayoutManager( this, 2, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false ) );

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById( R.id.drawer_layout );
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById( R.id.nav_view );
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close );
        drawer.addDrawerListener( toggle );
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener( this );

        mProgressCircle = findViewById( R.id.progress_circle1 );

        mUploads = new ArrayList<>();

        mUploads2 = new ArrayList<>();

        mUploads3 = new ArrayList<>();

        mHomeRecentPostList = new ArrayList<>();


        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "Images" );


        mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ImgUpload upload = postSnapshot.getValue( ImgUpload.class );
                    mUploads.add( upload );

                }
                Collections.reverse( mUploads );
                mAdapter = new UploadImgAdapter( ImagesListActivity.this, mUploads );


                mRecyclerView.setAdapter( mAdapter );

                mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener( ImagesListActivity.this );

                mProgressCircle.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );

                mAdapter.setItemClickListener( new ListItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(int position, View view) {

                    }
                } );


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText( ImagesListActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                mProgressCircle.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
            }
        } );


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById( R.id.drawer_layout );
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen( GravityCompat.START )) {
            drawer.closeDrawer( GravityCompat.START );
        } else {

            Intent a = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MAIN );
            a.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
            a.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
            startActivity( a );
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

            Intent intent = new Intent( this, ImagesListActivity.class );
            startActivity( intent );


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_images) {

            Intent intent = new Intent( this, ImagesActivity.class );
            startActivity( intent );

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_uploaad) {

            Intent intent = new Intent( this, ImageUpload.class );
            startActivity( intent );

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_create_category) {

            Intent intent = new Intent( this, MainActivity.class );
            startActivity( intent );

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact) {

            Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto", "someother@gmail.com", null ) );
            startActivity( Intent.createChooser( intent, "Choose an Email App :" ) );


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_privacy) {

            Intent intent = new Intent( this, Main3Activity.class );
            startActivity( intent );


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_rate) {

            Uri uri = Uri.parse( "market://details?id=" + getPackageName() );
            Intent goToMarket = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri );
            // To count with Play market backstack, After pressing back button,
            // to taken back to our application, we need to add following flags to intent.
            goToMarket.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK );
            try {
                startActivity( goToMarket );
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse( "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName() ) ) );
            }


        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById( R.id.drawer_layout );
        drawer.closeDrawer( GravityCompat.START );
        return true;
    }
}
```

Details.java

```
    package in.developerwithlove.nithiinhdwallpapers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Details extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Activity mActivity;
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ImgUpload> mItemList;
    private int mCurrentIndex;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private PostsPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = null;
    private TextView mTxtCounter, mBtnSetWall;
    private ImageButton mBtnFavorite, mBtnShare, mBtnDownloadWall;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private ProgressBar mProgressCircle;

    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mDataBaseRef;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_details );


        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById( R.id.pager );

        mTxtCounter = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.menus_counter );
        mBtnShare = (ImageButton) findViewById( R.id.menus_share );
        mBtnSetWall = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.menus_set_image );
        mBtnDownloadWall = (ImageButton) findViewById( R.id.menus_download_image );

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
        setSupportActionBar( toolbar );
        setTitle( "Wallpapers" );
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( true );

        mProgressCircle = findViewById( R.id.progressBar_detail );



        mItemList = new ArrayList<>();








    }


}
```

ImgUpload.java

```
    package in.developerwithlove.nithiinhdwallpapers;

public class ImgUpload {
    public String imageLink;
    public String category;
    public String fileName;


    public ImgUpload(){
    }

    public ImgUpload(String imageLink, String category, String fileName) {
        this.imageLink = imageLink;
        this.category = category;
        this.fileName = fileName;

    }



    public String getimageLink() {
        return imageLink;
    }

    public void setimageLink(String imageLink) {
        this.imageLink = imageLink;
    }

    public String getcategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setcategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getfileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setfileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }


}
```

UploadImgAdapter.java

```
    package in.developerwithlove.nithiinhdwallpapers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation;

import java.util.List;

public class UploadImgAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UploadImgAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<ImgUpload> mUploads;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    Bitmap bmImg = null;
    private ListItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
    private Activity ImagesActivity;

    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    public UploadImgAdapter(Context context, List<ImgUpload> Images) {

        mContext = context;
        mUploads = Images;

        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(mContext);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(v);




    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ImageViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final ImgUpload imgUpload = mUploads.get( position );


        holder.textViewName.setText(imgUpload.getfileName());



        Picasso.get()
                .load(imgUpload.getimageLink())
                .fit()
                .centerInside()
                .into(holder.imageView);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mUploads.size();
    }




    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,
            View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {

        public CardView cardView;
        public TextView textViewName;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public Button button;

        public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cardView = itemView.findViewById( R.id.card_view_top );
            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_img);


            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
            cardView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {

                }
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {


                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);



    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }


    public void setItemClickListener(ListItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }



}
```

PostPgerAdapter.java

```
    package in.developerwithlove.nithiinhdwallpapers;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
    import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;

    import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class PostsPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


    private Context mContext;

    private ArrayList<ImgUpload> mItemList;
    private ListItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public PostsPagerAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<ImgUpload> mItemList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mItemList = mItemList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from( mContext );
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView( (View) object );
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItemList.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup view, final int position) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.item_featuredpager, view, false );

        final TextView titleTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById( R.id.title_text );
        final ImageView imgPost = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById( R.id.post_img );
        final CardView cardView = (CardView) rootView.findViewById( R.id.card_view_top );

        final ImgUpload model = mItemList.get( position );

        // setting data over views
        String imgUrl = model.getimageLink();
        if (imgUrl != null && !imgUrl.isEmpty()) {
            Glide.with( mContext )
                    .load( imgUrl )
                    .into( imgPost );
        }

        titleTextView.setText( model.getfileName() );

        view.addView( rootView );


        cardView.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mItemClickListener != null) {
                    mItemClickListener.onItemClick( position, view );
                }
            }
        } );

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals( object );
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ListItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }
    }
```

Comment: sir there are many option you can achieve it this purpose. 1 => either when user click you can upload it in firebase and fetch it in other activity. 2=> the user click on the picture you can save the uri of the image in the globally list and access it in anywhere your application but when you close the application it will lose your data.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **600** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Here are the images what i want  [1](https://hmp.me/cqk9)      [2](https://hmp.me/cqla)    [3](https://hmp.me/cqlb)   [4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17vTv9MkBojLhkdo8u4QG1A01Oqk4XyoK)

Comment: I tried 1st option but I want like in above links 1,2,3,4 @HasnainSabir